# Degree ON or IN a field?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, collocations

I think that one can receive a degree in a field, say, Management. I saw somewhere that this was written on the first page of a thesis:

> Thesis for receiving «MA» degree **on** Translation Studies
>
> Topic: ...
>
> By: ...

Is using **on** with *degree* acceptable? I think it should be:

> Thesis for receiving «MA» degree **in** Translation Studies

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you rememberd the thesis correctly?

Usually it is

> A thesis **on** Translation Studies.

Since it is a written body *about* a subject.

and

> A degree **in** Translation Studies.

Since it is a degree spent studying **in** a subject.

[image]

Comment: Yes. I checked it now. Every student must follow the guideline, for example: *Thesis for receiving «M.Sc» degree on ...*. It seems odd to me. This is a university in a non-English speaking country. I think they might be wrong. And remember after on goes the name of the field, say medicine, not the subject of the thesis.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some relevant definitions:

> **in** *preposition*
>   14 — used to indicate a job or area of activity
>     ▪   She has a job in marketing.
>   [- Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/in)
>
> **on** *preposition*
>   9 — used to indicate the subject of something
>     ▪   a book on [=about] North American birds
>   [- Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/on)

“In” has the sense of “within the field of”, while “on” has the sense of “about” or “regarding” in the context of your quote.

Your quote has two possible antecedents to *on*: “thesis” and “degree”.

A thesis can be *on* a topic, meaning that it addresses that topic. So you can have, for example, a thesis on medicine - the thesis addresses aspects of medicine as a totality. You can also have a thesis *in* a topic or field, but that’s a looser tie between the thesis and the field. A thesis *in* medicine is one written about a medical topic, not necessarily about medicine as a whole.

Degrees are only awarded *in* fields of study, not *on* them. You can have a degree *in* (within the field of) medicine, but saying you have one *on* (about) medicine sounds odd.

The phrase “for receiving” also sounds a little off. It would be more natural to use the following wording:

- an «MA» degree was awarded for his thesis *in* Translation Studies *on* phrasing.